# Upload Multiple Documents to SharePoint Online using C#

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, .net, c-sharp, win-form

I've been trying for a while to make this work, but I'm stuck. I've checked all the solutions around here and google, but can't seem to figure out why I keep getting an error.

```
string targetFolder = "/sites/Test/Shared Documents/TestFolder";
string sourcePath = "C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\TestFolder\\";
string sharepointUrl = "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com";

ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(sharepointUrl);
clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securePassword);

Web web = clientContext.Web;
clientContext.Load(web);

Folder folder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(targetFolder);
clientContext.Load(folder);

DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath);
FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles("*.*");
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
    newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(sourcePath + file.Name);
    newFile.Url = sourcePath + file.Name;
    newFile.Overwrite = true;
    folder.Files.Add(newFile);
}

clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

It fails at clientContext.ExecuteQuery() with Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: 'File Not Found.'

Comment: Can you check if the newFile.Content is filled? And why you are as newFile.Url doing the FileSystem address? Change it to target folder, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code for your reference.

```
string targetSiteURL = @"https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/lz";
string targetFolder = "/sites/Test/Shared Documents/TestFolder";
string sourcePath = "C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\TestFolder\\";

var login = "lz@tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
var password = "xxx";

var securePassword = new SecureString();

foreach (char c in password)
{
    securePassword.AppendChar(c);
}
SharePointOnlineCredentials onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);

ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(targetSiteURL);
ctx.Credentials = onlineCredentials;
Web web = ctx.Web;
ctx.Load(web);

Folder folder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(targetFolder);
ctx.Load(folder);

DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath);
FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles("*.*");
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    var filePath = sourcePath + file.Name;
    FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();               
    newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(sourcePath + file.Name);
    newFile.Url = file.Name;
    newFile.Overwrite = true;
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File newspFile=folder.Files.Add(newFile);
}
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I had just a couple of lines different from mine. What actually made the difference and made it work was to add "/sites/Test" to my sharepointUrl which I noted that you had in yours. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if the newFile.Content is filled?

And why you are as newFile.Url doing the FileSystem address? Change it to target folder, right?

Or try use:

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(url))
{
     using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
     {
         var fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
         var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
         clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder);
         clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
         var fileUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}", list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, fi.Name);

         Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileUrl, fs, true);
     }
}
```

Comment: Yeah it gets filled:
  newFile.Content {byte[6]} byte[]
  [0] 116 byte
  [1] 101 byte
  [2] 115 byte
  [3] 116 byte
  [4] 32 byte
  [5] 49 byte
... I guess the system address got in there when I was trying something, I have it as "targetPath + file.Name" and it does not work... I tried to use that code you suggested, but it did not work :(

Comment: you need to edit my script a little bit, learn :)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I did edit the script to adapt to my code, but it did not work. Thanks for the learn tip, I'll make sure to do better in the future :)